# Laravel Releationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have one user table named "Users".

There are different roles (trainer and client).

I want to make like Trainer can have many clients, but client can have one trainer.

I made table in db like "ClientTrainer" where is stored only ID of users with columns

```
"id, client_id, trainer_id"
```

and I am trying to return something like this:

```
$user->allclients(); - return all clients (logged as trainer)

$user->owntrainer(); - return his trainer (logged as client)
```

Its fresh laravel 5.7 with only Auth and Roles.

I am sure it can only be done with modals, but i need a little help.

Thanks.

Comment: It's a rookie mistake to not separate the two entities, You will need sooner or later to separate between them; one can have a subscription the other cannot, one has a salary the other pays. You will build a middleware for each one and since you merge the two, you will have a third middleware that works for both. and so on and so forth. A simple structural mistake will lead to a lot of trouble (and a lot of `if()`s in the controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a model for table `ClientTrainer` as well. Then try this inside your Users model:

```
public function clients()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        "UsersModelNamespace", 
        "IntermediaryTableModelNamespace",
        "trainer_id",
        "client_id",
        "id",
        "id"
    );
}

public function trainer() // will return a collection with one element
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        "UsersModelNamespace", 
        "IntermediaryTableModelNamespace",
        "client_id",
        "trainer_id",
        "id",
        "id"
    );
}
```

Why I'm posting `belongsToMany` when retrieving the trainer? Laravel 5.7 does not support `hasOneThrough()` relationship.

Comment: Yes; make sure `ClientTrainer` is appended with the namespace (meaning: if file is located in `App` folder, then use `App\ClientTrainer`)

Comment: I did and when I printr $user->clients() it return blank page. Also for trainers.

EDIT: http://prntscr.com/racnub

Comment: Use it like this: `$user->clients`; `$user->trainer`

Comment: Glad it worked! If you want to return the trainer directly instead of a collection, you can use this: `$user->trainer()->first()`

Comment: Thanks for that, really appreciate your help

Comment: It's a rookie mistake to not separate the two entities

Comment: It depends on case. If OP doesn't plan on changing the role of users in future then yes, it's way better to split the table into `users` and `trainers`. Otherwise keeping both users in one table should be fine imo.

Comment: @N69S Can you explain why is it mistake?

Comment: @NikolaRanisavljev i explained it a bit on your question comments

Comment: Users will be only Clients and Trainer will have separate table? @N69S

Comment: @NikolaRanisavljev yes,that's the best approach, the relation between them will be an easy **HasMany** and **BelongsTo**

Comment: @N69S They are using the same login page, so that wont be problem?

Comment: @NikolaRanisavljev  Join me in the chat room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208852/laravel-releationship

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do is to separate your Table into two; "users" & "trainers".

Even if they have exactly the same fields, they dont have the same functionality, so that justifies the separation. Then just add `trainer_id` in your table "users"

Comment: I would not do this. You can add where clauses to relationships to get the same benefits without needing separate tables. Having more than one users table adds all sorts of complexities.

Comment: @ceejayoz I agree with you. So, how can I achieve that? I need it in modal so I can anytime get Trainer or Clients

Comment: I support this answer/architecture, when you get to the point where you need to establish relationships within the same table you are needing at least one more to make your db structure clear and readable to others. Also it's there is a big chance you will need specific data to those roles once you create a relationship. 

You could also try "clients" and "trainers"